# I'm a White Hat and I develop my own viruses. Should I report it when almost all scanners say the executable is safe?

Tags: antivirus, disclosure

I develop my own viruses for 'scientific' purposes, namely to see if they pass the test of Virustotal.com. They all do, except for one or two scanners. Is this considered something you should report to Microsoft/McAfee/etc? If yes, how?

Comment: With respect to 'how' I'd suggest studying this kind of thing and the links at the end of the doc:
https://www.icann.org/en/system/files/files/vulnerability-disclosure-05aug13-en.pdf

That should also help you investigate if it's a 'yes' as well.

Comment: btw: Which scanners do detect your viruses?

Comment: When you upload to Virustotal, it gets sent to the AV companies. Sorry, no source handy, just my recollection.

Comment: Making a virus that avoids AV detection is actually pretty simple. The real deal is exploiting bugs in applications / OS to allow something you shouldn't be supposed to do - for example, a non-administrator running your "virus" elevated. With all the RnD into heuristics, most of AV detection is still based on matching the file to a list of known viruses - that's why it's so important to keep your AV detection files up to date. If you use AV in the first place, of course :)

Comment: @marstato I think this is a "what if" kind of question.

Comment: John D, write a post on how your code avoids detection and let the *community* know (hearing Stallman's voices wooo).

Comment: is a bash script that simply runs `rm -rf /` a virus?

Comment: @Petah Yes, since there is hardly any legitimate purpose for doing so. `rm -rf .` would be a better example.

Comment: @Sebb well its not according to VirusTotal https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/7a3bd27aacb62ae8b936d71d2cfd6918b748de0b7ea5cf229140027a7ffc732a/analysis/1458082715/

Comment: @Petah Which is known to not detect some virus, see the question ;) We both have the same point, I just stated that this is most probably evil and therefore not the best example for the vague definition of virus .

Comment: @Sebb: [What about `rm -rf ${DESTDIR}/` (and forget to setenv DESTDIR)?](https://github.com/valvesoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/3671)

Comment: @BenVoigt It's a bug, I assume ;) I guess you can best define a virus by its malicious intention (or theoretical intention). You could of course "forget" to set it, but never assume malice when stupidity will suffice.

Comment: @Sebb: So all viruses need to do to get past scans is to look stupid?

Comment: @BenVoigt A car accident wont stop hurting by being an accident, you still need protection. That's why we call it 'accident' and not 'car murder'. Back to reality, as Petah tested, it works.

Comment: It needs to do something malicious.  What do your viruses do, while not getting caught?

Comment: @Petah: It doesn't reproduce, does it?

Comment: Fellow whitehat here, nearly none of my viruses get detected, even if they are keyloggers (corporate employee trackers) or RATs (corporate remote control). What gets them flagged is elevation exploits.

Answer (score 136):

That's a pointless exercise.

Most malware scanners match on fragments of binary code (aka virus signatures), and they check MD5 hashes of known infected code against their blacklists.  Unless the virus you wrote has been deployed into the wild and is already on their blacklist, there isn't a chance they'll have your code's exact signatures on file.

The scanners that do trigger a match are most likely those using heuristics, which scan for "suspicious" behavior.  For example, very few programs legitimately need to request the OS grant them the privilege to "Act as a debugger", yet that's fairly common behavior in malware, so if they find it they'll flag it.

Reporting your custom viruses to McAfee won't help anyone - not McAfee, not the public.  If they don't identify your code as a virus, it's because their scanners don't have very effective heuristics (which they already know, and won't learn from your code among the hundreds of viruses they analyze per day.) And developing a match takes a researcher time and effort, which costs McAfee money.  There is no value to McAfee to waste money on researching a virus that nobody can get, and adding it to their blacklists, because as a white hat you won't allow it to be released.

Comment: @JohnDoe I think John might have gone a little far pointing out that you have to be careful about your white hat status. Just saying you're white hat doesn't make you white hat. Instead, making sure any code you write can't be used for malicious purposes is the critical action. Maybe he overplayed and implied you aren't careful with your code, when what he was probably trying to say is, "Just in case, please do us all a favor and be *very* careful with your code".

Comment: The important part of the answer which could be made clearer is that "virus scanners" are **nothing but blacklists** of known, found-in-the-wild virus code and code fragments. Some AV tools also detect suspicious/virus-like *behavior*, but they're likely to have lots of false positives and break things the user may want to work.

Comment: The only exception I would make to the above is if you are wanting to share a proof of concept of virus that takes advantage of an undiscovered exploit. Then I would submit samples and code with the appropriate security researchers and/or the affected software vendors to help aid in protecting the public.

Answer (score 4):

you should not, actually - there's nothing obliging you to do so. You said you're white hat, so you're not intended to rob a bank using your code, and your personal research results are your very own and private unless you **wish** to publish them somewhere.

Comment: What if OP wants to help AV publishers to strengthen their heuristics so he'll feel safer using the products himself? Even if OP only cared about himself, he might want to report his finding. Maybe he'll even get a dollar or two, or even a job offer.

Comment: @Kay sounds reasonable, and I propose for OP to publish it in his blog or in security-related journal. He'll have at least +1 scientific publication, and the reach will be not just the AV makers, but a much broader security researchers community.

Comment: @Kay Sharing is always a good idea and benefits community. Still I find that any kind of publishing is philosophically probably a selfish act even though it would be generally deemed selfless.

Comment: @Mikuz taking care about yourself is good, and there's no shame to write your name next to your achievemnts

Comment: @Alexey Vesnin Yes, I totally support all this kind of behaviour. Also, I find that it's good for people to take care of themselves and be selfish. This is getting way out of topic though.